# Extract a complete sentence using a QRegularExpression

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I am currently trying to extract the following sentence:

> This is a rectangle. Its height is 193, its width is 193 and the word number is 12.

from the following line:

> ID: 1 x: 1232 y: 2208 w: 193 h: 390 wn: 12 ln: 13 c: This is a rectangle. Its height is 193, its width is 193 and the word number is 12 !

I have to do this using QRegularExpressions. Therefore, my code is as following:

```
regularExpression.setPattern("[c:](?:\\s*)$");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regularExpression.match("ID: 2 x: 845 y: 1633 w: 422 h: 491 wn: 78 ln: 12 c: qsdfgh");
if (match.hasMatch()) {
    QString id = match.captured(0);
    qDebug()<<"The annotation is:"<<id;
    return id;
}
return 0;
```

However, it does not work at all and I do not understand why (maybe my regular expression is not correct).I am stuck in this problem from several days now.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: "I have to do this using QRegularExpressions”. Why?

Comment: Hi Frank, I have to do it using QRegularExpressions because I am actually using Qt.

Comment: Not sure if QRegularExp.. works differently but how about this? regularExpression.setPattern("c:\s*(.*$)");

Comment: Hi Simo. It works like a charm. I appreciate your help. Thank you so much :)

Comment: If that was the answer, please add it as such one. /cc @SimoErkinheimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following regex to parse everything after **c:** and to also remove possible white space from the beginning of the string:

```
regularExpression.setPattern("c:\s*(.*$)");
```